# How to safely embed a Twitter widget with Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, twitter, content-security-policy

I have a feature that allows users to embed selected widgets from Twitter using [their API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/overview). The code is very simply:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"
 href="https://twitter.com/twitterdev">
Tweets by @TwitterDev
<script type="text/javascript" 
      src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

I have a fairly restrictive Content Security Policy on my site that looks something like `script-src platform.twitter.com etc` among others. The widget fails to load, with a CSP error from cdn.syndication.twimg.com I don't want to whitelist that site under script-src though, since it seems like an invitation for an attack.

Is there a better way to embed widgets from Twitter securely?

CodePen example: https://codepen.io/dandormont-the-decoder/pen/NWjQoVG

Comment: Can you share a bit more on why you believe a Twitter-controlled domain is more of a risk than `platform.twitter.com`?

Comment: Because platform.twitter.com just hosts the Twitter codebase itself whereas twimg.com hosts user generated content. I don't understand why Twitter needs to execute user generated content as a script.